# Is it possible to get actual return code of a command executed in Azure container using "az container exec"?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-cli, azure-container-instances

When I execute a command in an ACI container instance using `az container exec`, I always get return code 0 even if the command executed within the container fails (of course if the `az` command as such runs without errors).

Is there any way how I could get the actual return code for that executed 'sub-command'?
How can I verify that the command succeeded, esp. for cases when the command is executed in an automated manner (e.g. in pipeline)?

**Example**

```
az container exec --resource-group <resource-group> --name <name> --container-name <container-name> --exec-command "cp /tmp/testfile1.txt /tmp/new/"
```

If the `testfile1.txt` does not exist the inner `cp` command fails, however, the outer `az` command still returns code 0.

Comment: Any update on this ?? Could you please let us know if the answer is helpful. If the provided solution worked, could you please accept it as answer to help other community members for the similar issue .Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to execute command in ACR & can able to copy the files from one to another .
Here are the steps:

- Created an Container instance

Using below `cmd` to  connect with container (OS-LINUX) .

```
az container exec --resource-group <name> --name <containername> --exec-command "/bin/sh"
```

And created new folder and file inside container .
[image]

Run the below command to copy files to another folder ;

```
az container exec --resource-group <name> --name <name> --container-name <name> --exec-command "cp /usr/src/app/tmp/testfile1.txt /usr/src/app/tmp/new1/"
```

***NOTE: Make sure that for the above `cmd` you have added your path correctly where the file is exist***

[image]

When got succeeded it returns nothing , if there is any file not available(e.g `testfile2.txt`) then it will return the exit code 1 .

[image]

For more information please refer this MS DOC: [Execute a command in a running Azure container instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec)